# How to edit agsm.bst file to change how the URL is outputted in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

From the agsm.bst file, the output produced in the bibliography would be something like this:

[image]

for the following file:

```
@article{Shaffer2004,
author = {Shaffer, David Williamson and Squire, Kurt R and Gee, James P},
journal = {Phi Delta Kappan},
pages = {104--111},
number = {2},
title = {{Video games and the future of learning}},
url = {http://website.education.wisc.edu/kdsquire/tenure-files/23-pdk-VideoGamesAndFutureOfLearning.pdf},
volume = {87},
year = {2004}
}
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the following lines in the agsm.bst file:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ URL empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ }
```

However, instead of **URL:** before the url appearing, I want to change this to "Available from: http://....."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to use the package `biblatex` together with `biber`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Shaffer2004,
  author = {Shaffer, David Williamson and Squire, Kurt R and Gee, James P},
  journal = {Phi Delta Kappan},
  pages = {104--111},
  number = {2},
  title = {{Video games and the future of learning}},
  url =  {http://website.education.wisc.edu/kdsquire/tenure-files/23-pdk-VideoGamesAndFutureOfLearning.pdf},
  volume = {87},
  year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available from\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\usepackage{xurl}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

foo~\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Run with `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex`:

[image]